# How to make nested resources restrictive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, nested

So I have my web app setup allowing a user to create a project which can only be seen by their team. Within the project, tasks can be created. I'd like for these tasks to be restricted only to the project they were created under. However, when I create two separate projects and navigate to the view screen I am seeing the same tasks under each project.

TasksController

```
def index
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

  @task = project.tasks

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @tasks }
  end
  @task = Task.order('title').page(params[:page]).per(4)
end

def show
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

  @task = project.tasks.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @task }
  end
end
```

ProjectsController

```
def index
  @project = current_account.projects
end

def show
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

routes

```
resources :projects do 
        resources :tasks
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is a matter using @task and @tasks

```
def index
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

  # if I follow your program
  # this should be @tasks 
  @tasks = project.tasks

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    # here you render @tasks
    format.xml  { render :xml => @tasks }
  end
  @task = Task.order('title').page(params[:page]).per(4)
end

def show
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

  @task = project.tasks.find(params[:id])

  # simple check makesure @task is child of project
    if @task.project_id == project.id
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html # show.html.erb
         format.xml  { render :xml => @task }
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, I made this adjustment. But its still not doing what I expected.

Comment: ok may I know in what controller the program still not doing right index / show ?

Comment: so I have project/1 and project/2    I can go into project/2 and see tasks from project/1 I want them to be restricted to which ever project and user they were created under. I believe tasks controller index is where there needs to be more code. I know I could try using Can Can but would prefer to maybe roll my own authorization instead.

Comment: I just edited my answer see bottom area for show method

Comment: I believe something like this would work but its the index page that needs this restriction. unless I could maybe change the links to the show page instead. let me try

Comment: Yea idk still having this problem I really appreciate your help though. Something I am going to have to work later this evening.